# Raw folder files are not included in Android release build in latest gradle version

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mp3, raw

### Description:

- Added mp3 file under `res/raw` folder in Android native code to play mp3 file in app which is working in debug build but not able to play in release build.

### Issue:

- As per APK analysis, raw folder for debug build is included in apk but the same code doesn't include mp3 in the release build apk so the app is not able to play mp3 in the release build. [Currently using latest Gradle version]

### Observation:

1. Gradle with the latest version is not able to include the raw folder in the release build:

   - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip`
   - `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'`
   - **Full sample demo:** https://urlis.net/8ntun
2. Gradle with the old version is working and able to include raw folder files in release build.

   - `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`
   - `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'`
   - **Full sample demo:** https://urlis.net/fz8f9

Let me know how we can make it working in the release build with the latest Gradle version.